# Optimize Phone Storage: Underlying logic?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, photos

I've trawled the web for info on iCloud Photo Library's "Optimize Phone Storage" option on iOS, but can't figure out the exact logic applied.

From [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204264):

> iCloud Photo Library will automatically manage the size of your library on your device, so you can make the most of your device's storage and access more photos than ever

I assume the device will cache high-res photos up to a point, but what is this point in terms of MB remaining on the device?

In addition, does iCloud Photo Library perform any housekeeping on that cache, e.g. clearing out high-res copies you've not viewed in n days - if so what is n?

Comment: I have no proof, but I think the answers to this question all depend on how much space is available.   40g free and 1gb  free are two different things... Likewise tho your on to it... It caches photos and makes space as needed.  It likely wants to balance things 3 ways, live in cache as long as possible to minimize bandwidth used.

Comment: This question may be near impossible to answer at least now as Apple hasn't, that I'm aware of, released that information. From when I had that (terrible, IMO) feature enabled, it kept the device quite close to full - 1 to 2GB or less, I believe. And yes, with that iCloud clears higher resolution images out when you need more space. The inherit problem is that *you* can't control which high res media to keep (for offline viewing, for example). That may not be a problem for most, but was for me.

Comment: I thought as much, yeah more control over the storage would be beneficial to me at least, maybe it's not deemed massively important by most consumers? Thanks anyway guys